# Classification for involutory real infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inverse-function

Out of curiosity I'm playing around with the concept of involutory functions. An involutory function (*involution*) is a function whose composition with itself is the identity function (i.e. ${f \circ f} = id$). In other words, involutions are functions that are their own inverses (i.e. $f = f^{-1}$).

Applying this concept to univariate real polynomials; it seems that all involutory polynomials have degree one(!) and belong to one of these two families:

1. $id$: $id(x) = x$ (the identity function, trivially involutory)
2. $p_1$: $p_1(x) = {-x + c}$, for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$

One well-known generalization of polynomials are infinite series, so that raises the question: *Is there some pretty classification of involutory real infinite series, too?*

Surely the examples will be richer than for polynomials.